# WebView2controller bounds is (0,0,0,0)

Tags: visual-c++, webview2

Even though I called the `put_Bounds` function of webview2controller, I get (0,0,0,0) when I try `get_Bounds`.

Also, if `controller->close()` closes the dialog, an 'Access violation reading location' error occurs.

Even when the controller is initialized with the `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions` function, the result value is `S_OK`, so I don't know why the problem occurs.

Please help if you have had a similar problem or know a solution.

Below is the initialization code.

```
void CWebBrowser::InitializeWebView()
{
    CloseWebView();

    CString subFolder = GetInstallPath();
    CString appData = GetUserDataFolder();
    ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions* options = nullptr;

    HRESULT hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
        subFolder,
        appData,
        options,
        Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
            this,
            &CWebBrowser::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get());

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CString text;
        if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
        {
            text = L"Cannot found the WebView2 component.";
        }
        else
        {
            text = L"Cannot create the webview environment.";
        }

        ShowFailure(hr, text);
    }
}

HRESULT CWebBrowser::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted(
    HRESULT result,
    ICoreWebView2Environment* environment)
{
    CHECK_FAILURE(result);

    if (!environment)
        return E_FAIL;

    CHECK_FAILURE(environment->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment)));
    CHECK_FAILURE(environment->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment2)));

    CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(
        m_hWnd,
        Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(
            this,
            &CWebBrowser::OnCreateWebViewControllerCompleted).Get()));

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT CWebBrowser::OnCreateWebViewControllerCompleted(
    HRESULT result,
    ICoreWebView2Controller* controller)
{
    if (result == S_OK)
    {
        if (controller != nullptr)
        {
            m_pImpl->m_webController = controller;
            CHECK_FAILURE(controller->get_CoreWebView2(&m_pImpl->m_webView));

            if (!m_pImpl->m_webView)
                return E_FAIL;

            CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pImpl->m_webView2)));
            CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pImpl->m_webView2_16)));

            CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->get_Settings(&m_pImpl->m_webSettings));

            RegisterEventHandlers();

            ResizeToClientArea();
        }

        auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::CreationCompleted];
        if (callback != nullptr)
            RunAsync(callback);
    }
    else
    {
        ShowFailure(result, L"Cannot create webview environment.");
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```